# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Arts & Crafts breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 0 | 7 |
| Users destroyed | 2 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 1 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue | 32 | 70 |
| Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue | 1 | 5 |
| Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue | 2 | 50 |
| Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue | 7 | 96 |
| Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue | 25 | 366 |
| Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue | 13 | 106 |
| Questions reopened | 2 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 1 | 2 |
| Questions migrated | 1 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁴ | 2 | 85 |
| Questions closed | 68 | 10 |
| Question flags handled⁴ | 34 | 53 |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 0 |
| Posts undeleted | 2 | 2 |
| Posts locked | 1 | 14 |
| Posts deleted⁵ | 41 | 90 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 50 |
| Comments undeleted | 1 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 0 | 32 |
| Comments deleted⁶ | 71 | 70 |
| Comment flags handled | 11 | 21 |
| Answers flagged | 4 | 117 |
| Answer flags handled | 98 | 23 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Awesome, I love seeing the community do more work than me :)