# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers?
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Arts & Crafts over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 0 | 6 |
| Users destroyed³ | 7 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 2 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 1 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 46 | 162 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 0 | 19 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 3 | 99 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 1 | 67 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 1 | 338 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 10 | 153 |
| Tags merged | 1 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 1 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 1 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 1 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 7 | 2 |
| Questions protected | 2 | 7 |
| Questions migrated | 17 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 3 | 128 |
| Questions closed | 79 | 19 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 54 | 77 |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 4 |
| Posts undeleted | 1 | 3 |
| Posts locked | 2 | 46 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 55 | 127 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 14 |
| Comments undeleted | 1 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 2 | 41 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 83 | 123 |
| Comment flags handled | 18 | 25 |
| Bounties canceled | 1 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 9 | 216 |
| Answer flags handled | 156 | 69 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 4 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...